# Issues creating a D3 tooltip for line graph

Tags: d3.js, tooltip, linegraph

I am trying to recreate the tooltip from this site (http://www.d3noob.org/2014/07/my-favourite-tooltip-method-for-line.html) for my dual axis line graph. However I keep running into an error where the circle only appears at the top right point of the graph and I get the error

TypeError: d1 is undefined on line 137

I keep searching for solution sbut have yet to find any so any help would be apprecated.

Heres the code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <script type="text/javascript">

 // http://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/PIT/attend.shtml

 /* want interactive line chart showing two lines, total attendance and      attendance per game
    cicles at vaious points that show information on hover about why attendance may be drastically different
    ie opening of pnc park or world series team */

// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
var margin = {top: 30, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 150},
    width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Method used for finding year corresponding with mouse location   
var bisectYear = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d.Year; }).left;

// Set the ranges
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y0 = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
var y1 = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .tickFormat(d3.format(".0f"))
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxisLeft = d3.svg.axis().scale(y0)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(5);

var yAxisRight = d3.svg.axis().scale(y1)
    .orient("right").ticks(5)

// Define the first line
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.Year); })
    .y(function(d) { return y0(d.AttendancePerG); });

// Define the second line
var valueline2 = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.Year); })
    .y(function(d) { return y1(d.Wins); });

// Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", 
            "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");           

///////////////////
var lineSvg = svg.append("g");                             // **********

var focus = svg.append("g")                                // **********
    .style("display", "none");                             // **********
///////////////////

// Get the data
d3.csv("piratesAttendance.csv", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.Year = +d.Year;
        d.AttendancePerG = +d.AttendancePerG
        d.Wins = +d.Wins;
    });

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.Year; }));
    y0.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.AttendancePerG; })]);
    y1.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.Wins; })]);

    // Add the valueline path.
    svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", valueline(data))
        .attr("stroke", "gray")
        .attr("stroke-width",2)
        .attr("fill","none");

    // Add the second valueline path.
    svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", valueline2(data))
        .attr("stroke", "gold")
        .attr("stroke-width",2)
        .attr("fill","none");

    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    // Add the Left Y Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .style("fill","gray")
        .call(yAxisLeft);

    // Add the Right Y Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + ",0)")
        .style("fill","gold")
        .call(yAxisRight);

    /////////////
    // append the circle at the intersection               // **********
    focus.append("circle")                                 // **********
        .attr("class", "y")                                // **********
        .style("fill", "none")                             // **********
        .style("stroke", "blue")                           // **********
        .attr("r", 4);                                     // **********

    // append the rectangle to capture mouse               // **********
    svg.append("rect")                                     // **********
        .attr("width", width)                              // **********
        .attr("height", height)                            // **********
        .style("fill", "none")                             // **********
        .style("pointer-events", "all")                    // **********
        .on("mouseover", function() { focus.style("display", null); })
        .on("mouseout", function() { focus.style("display", "none"); })
        .on("mousemove", mousemove);                       // **********

    function mousemove() {                                 // **********
        var x0 = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]),              // **********
            i = bisectYear(data, x0, 1),                   // **********
            d0 = data[i - 1],                              // **********
            d1 = data[i],                                  // **********
            d = x0 - d0.date > d1.date - x0 ? d1 : d0;     // **********

    focus.select("circle.y")                           // **********
        .attr("transform",                             // **********
              "translate(" + x(d.Year) + "," +         // **********
                             y0(d.AttendancePerG) + ")");        // **********
}                                                      // **********
});

 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Can you make this into a jsfiddle or a plunk so we can see the issue? Or at least share what piratesAttendance.csv looks like?

Comment: Not sure why you're getting `d1 is undefined`, at least, not without seeing your data and debugging some things, but shouldn't `d = x0 - d0.date > d1.date - x0 ? d1 : d0;` be `d = x0 - d0.Year > d1.Year - x0 ? d1 : d0;`

Comment: @HenryS heres the jsfiddle with the csv in the html http://jsfiddle.net/SR34/1dtvxrjk/#&togetherjs=91PUASCGP7

Comment: @BenLyall you're right it should be d0.Year and d1.Year thanks for the catch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a plunk with the fixed code: http://plnkr.co/edit/Xj2ZyxqrY2PJVV0FML26

There were several issues here.

Firstly, your data wasn't sorted by date (earliest to latest), which was preventing the `bisectYear` function from working properly (it was always returning `1`). Fixed by adding:

```
data.sort(function(a, b) { return a.Year - b.Year; });
```

Secondly, your date (year) values weren't being parsed to `Date` objects, which was causing a range of problems. Essentially, your time scale was running from 1891ms to 2014ms, rather than the years 1891 to 2014! I added this at the point where you read in the CSV:

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.Year =  parseDate(d.Year)
    ...
```

with a new function to parse into a `Date` just based on the full year:

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y").parse;
```

Comment: I guess I was under the impression that since there were no time day month elements I didnt need to consider the year as a date. This worked great thank you so much @HenryS